# HOW TO CHANGE PRODUCT VIEW in magento 1.9.2.4 8 (I FIX IT)

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

this is how is it in this moment 
[image]

and this is how we want

[image]

where and who we can chage it

hope someone can help

Comment: With out  your template design its hard to chnage this thing

Comment: ok , wich file you need

Comment: app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml open this file and start customizing. :)

Comment: ok , is to hart for me , how much if i hire someone ?

Comment: The question is very vague. To customize Magento, you need to understand it, there is not just one template per page. Before you jump into the scene, inform yourself about the Magento template mechanism. If you don't have the patience, hire someone who can do it for you, you will save yourself a lot of trouble

Comment: yea i unterstand but i dont think it will be hi cost ? or yes ?

Comment: Here's not the place to hire Magento developer. Why not google, eg: Magento freelancer.

Comment: yes of course , i was asking aybe is was not so hard to change the code someone can write a guide :-)

Comment: @Yasin2018 if you are not developer , thats fine.... if you want to be developer than better to learn magento, once you learn you can do any kind of customization, so instead of hiring someone if you want to take community help, its better to learn atleast liitle bit about magento.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento YE IM BEGINNER all the shop i have do for my person and i learn every day , but of course begiiner need help i think

Comment: @Yasin2018 than definately you need help, i complete agree , good luck.....

Comment: @Yasin2018, can you please share your website's url?

Comment: www.muslimas-shop.com

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara muslimas-shop.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Template file(phtml) actually are structured by many different "block".
So, you need to learn the knowledge of the relationship of block and template. And learn the relationship about the module and front design.

In your case, you can find out the template file of Product detail page at app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/produ‌​ct/view.phtml

and there are different blocks like "addto", "priceHtml", etc.

For Beginner, there have many good guide of magento at internet like [Alan Storm's guide](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento/).